# How to make auth page in Laravel 10?

Tags: laravel-10

In the previous version I made auth page using the command `php artisan make:auth`.
But this instruction is not efficient in the latest version.

Command `make:auth` is not defined. Did you mean one of these?

⇂ make:cast
⇂ make:channel
⇂ make:command
⇂ make:component
⇂ make:controller
⇂ make:event
⇂ make:exception
⇂ make:factory
⇂ make:job
⇂ make:listener
⇂ make:mail
⇂ make:middleware
⇂ make:migration
⇂ make:model
⇂ make:notification
⇂ make:observer
⇂ make:policy
⇂ make:provider
⇂ make:request
⇂ make:resource
⇂ make:rule
⇂ make:scope
⇂ make:seeder
⇂ make:test
⇂ make:view